# A div and the rest of the html after that doesnt show in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a web page im designing as a responsive web design.in there i have a div which contains the sign up button of a email sign up form.in IE this and the content after that doesnt show up. following is the problematic html code..

```
<div class="Sign_Up">
    <button id="submit" class="bt btn btn-alt" type="submit">
</div>
```

and when i remove this code the site works fine
the css for the class is like this

```
.Social_Base .Social_Part .Detail_Box .Sign_Up .bt {
    background: url("http://media.expedia.com/media/content/expaus/images/socialbar/Social_main_bg.png") no-repeat scroll -374px -43px transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 33px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 122px;
}
```

please help me..its ie9..it should be okay..i have used a complete image and positioned it to get the image for the sign up button..if any1 could help..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a close button tag.

```
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must complete this tag :

```
<div class="Sign_Up">
    <button id="submit" class="bt btn btn-alt" type="submit">your text</button>
</div>
```